# why we need to go for xml binders instead of xml parsers in java

Tags: xml, binders

why we need to go for xml binders instead of xml  parsers in java

Answer (score 2):

We don't. Both have their separate uses.

- [XML data binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_data_binding)
- [parsing XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Programming_interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need to use XML binders, XML data binders converts XML into objects, because
objects are usually more familiar with developers. Most of the tasks can be accomplished without object binder, using DOM or VTD-XML parsers, you can just navigate the XML tree, and you should be able to accomplish the same thing as XML binders